# set interface name in a variable with jinja loop on ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

i want to set inside a variable interface name if is equals to a variable pass on command line so i'm using jinja like this :

```
- name: Inizializzo la rete
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: stampo interfacce
      set_fact:
        privata: "{% for interfacce in ansible_interfaces %} {% set int_tmp = 'ansible_facts.' ~ interfacce ~ '.macaddress' %} {% if {{int_tmp}}==mac_privata %} {{interfacce}} {% endif %} {% endfor %}"
    - name: Stampo
      debug:
        msg: "{{privata}}"
```

but it doesn't works
i call this :

```
ansible-playbook test.yml --extra-vars "mac_privata=00:50:56:b7:bc:f1"
```

i do this because i've more than three interface
where i'm wrong?

EDIT:
@mdaniel
Thanks for your answer but it seems that it doesn't substitute hostvars['ansible_' ~ interfacce ~ '.macaddress'] with content of ansible_ens32.macaddress.
For example i do this :

```
    - name: Stampo
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_ens32.macaddress }}"
```

i've this output :

```
TASK [Stampo] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.150.20.130] => {
    "msg": "00:50:56:b7:bb:f1"
}
```

but if i do this :

```
    - name: stampo interfacce
      set_fact:
        privata: >-
          {%- for interfacce in ansible_interfaces -%}
            {%- if interfacce != 'lo' -%}
              {%- set int_tmp = hostvars['ansible_' ~ interfacce ~ '.macaddress'] -%}
              {%- if int_tmp == mac_privata -%}
                {{ interfacce }}
              {%- endif -%}
            {%- endif -%}
          {%- endfor -%}
    - name: Stampo
      debug:
        msg: "{{privata}}"
```

I'm expecting name of interface with mac_privata macaddress in privata variable if i do this :

```
ansible-playbook test.yml --extra-vars "mac_privata=00:50:56:b7:bb:f1"
```

i've ens_32 but it's empty:

```
TASK [stampo interfacce] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /mnt/c/Users/francesco.ferraro/ansible_test/test.yml:7
ok: [10.150.20.130] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "privata": ""
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time one sees `{{` inside another jinja2 context, it's almost certainly not what you what to happen. To dynamically look up a variable, use either `vars[""]` or `hostvars[""]`, or if you prefer the [`lookup("vars", "")`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/lookup/vars.html)

```yaml
  privata: >-
     {%- for interfacce in ansible_interfaces -%}
     {%- set int_tmp = vars['ansible_facts.' ~ interfacce ~ '.macaddress'] -%}
     {%- if int_tmp == mac_privata -%}
     {{ interfacce }}
     {%- endif -%}
     {%- endfor -%}
```

Most cases support the conditional `for` loop, which can make the snippet a little shorter

```yaml
  privata: >-
     {%- for interfacce in ansible_interfaces
         if mac_privata == vars['ansible_facts.' ~ interfacce ~ '.macaddress'] -%}
     {{ interfacce }}
     {%- endfor -%}
```

Comment: i've answer below because was too long the answer, but thanks anyway

Comment: You mentioned using `hostvars` but did you try `vars` or the `lookup` filter? I have a very hard time imagining a situation where `debug: var=ansible_ens32.macaddress` emits something but `debug: {var: vars["ansible_" ~ "ens32" ~ ".macaddress"]}` does not -- I **can**, easily, imagine that `ens32` is not present in `ansible_interfaces`, which would also do what you described

Comment: I also just noticed the cygwin `/mnt/c` in your example, so doing all this inside cygwin or WSL or whatever similarly could screw up your experience

Comment: i've try right now on a linux vm but this:
```
msg: "{{ lookup('vars','ansible_' ~ 'ens224' ~ '.macaddress') }}"
```
give me that error 
```
fatal: [172.16.5.205]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: No variable found with this name: ansible_ens224.macaddress\n\nThe error appears to be in '/root/test.yml': line 18, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n          {%- endfor -%}\n    - name: Stampo\n      ^ here\n"}
```
i think problem is newline

Comment: on target machine i've that ens224 
```
3: ens224: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:b7:25:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.5.205/24 brd 172.16.5.255 scope global noprefixroute ens224
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5711:7543:f95b:f31f/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: i've solved with this :

{%- set int_tmp = lookup('vars','ansible_'~interfacce).macaddress -%}